# Python - Drag and drop into terminal as input? MacOS -zsh

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, terminal, command-line-arguments

Code Sample:

```
from pathlib import Path
myfile =input('Enter the absolute path or drag a file into the terminal:')
myfileStripped= Path(myfile).read_text().replace('\n','').replace('　','').split('。')
print('Stripping file...')
```

I am writing code that takes a filepath as input. It works if I copy/paste the path into terminal but not when I drag and drop the file into the terminal window. I think it's because the terminal escapes the spaces in the pathname so the string returned by input() ends up pointing to a directory that doesn't exist.

In case I didn't do a good job explaining:

The path: '/Downloads/Kappa  - Akutagawa  Ryuunosuke.txt'

Becomes: '/Downloads/Kappa\ \ -\ Akutagawa\ \ Ryuunosuke.txt' if I drag the file into a terminal window. Which, as a string, points to nothing.

Is there a way to turn off the auto-escape behavior of terminal? Or a better way to write this code?

I prefer drag and drop for this particular workflow so I don't mind if a solution breaks the ability to manually type in the path.

Thank you.

Comment: What OS, and which terminal?

Comment: (In general, escaping spaces is the _correct_ thing to do. Either that, or quoting the whole thing.)

Comment: Updated--- macOs and zsh?

Comment: Why not just unescaping ? `myfile = '/private/tmp/3\\ 522.dat '.replace('\\ ', ' ').strip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily unescape the path:

```
myfile =input('Enter the absolute path or drag a file into the terminal:')
Enter the absolute path or drag a file into the terminal:/private/tmp/3\ 522.dat
print(myfile)
myfile = myfile.replace('\\ ', ' ').strip()
os.path.exists(myfile)
```

Output:

```
/private/tmp/3 522.dat
True
```

Comment: Wow thank you, you wizard! This thought came up but I got stuck because I didn't realize/remember that variables could be reassigned haha. Thanks again!